# Update all Account Names

Tags: batch

I have updated all my Accounts through Batch Apex.

E.g.:

- Account1 xyz
- Account2 xyz
- Account3 xyz

But I want to remove '*xyz*' (Product Name) from all the Account names.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: How you are populating `xyz` with account name

Comment: 'code'   for(Account a : scope)
        {
            a.Name = a.Name + 'xyz';
        }
        update scope;

Comment: If you need to remove `xyz` then why appending with name?

Comment: they want accounts product wise

Comment: Don't they need account product wise now?

Comment: Are the product names appended to the account name with space between them?

Comment: yes I gave the space

Comment: use replace,split method of the string..https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how many Accounts you currently have. If it is less than 5000 or close to that, you can simply do it via execute anonymous block. Here is the code:

```
List<Account> accToUpdate = [Select Id, Name From Account Where Name Like '%xyz' limit 5000];
for(Account acc: [Select Id, Name From Account Where Name Like '%xyz' limit 5000]) {
    acc.Name = acc.Name.substringBeforeLast('xyz');
}
update accToUpdate;
```

If you have millions of records - translate that into batch.